# How do I know which value in range 'hit' on select with left join?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have this (MySQL) statement:

```
   SELECT h.*
     FROM houses h 
LEFT JOIN avail a ON (h.id = a.house_id
                 AND (    a.date_occupied = '2012-03-07'
                       OR a.date_occupied = '2012-03-08'
                       OR a.date_occupied = '2012-03-09'
                       OR a.date_occupied = '2012-03-10'))
    WHERE sleeps_count >= '1'
      AND active = 1
      AND a.house_id IS NULL
ORDER BY h.name
```

Is there a way to get the 'date_occupied' that matched returned in the results? Or do I have manually go through the results and then figure out which date is actually the one that hit?

Comment: Add the `a.date_occupied` column to the SELECT list ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590947/how-do-i-know-which-condition-worked-on-sql-select

Comment: What you are asking does not make sense. Since you are using date_occupied to *exclude* rows from the result set, you can't return the date that matched in the results.

Comment: @IkeWalker The `date_occupied`, for any row in the resultset, must be one of the four specified dates, or NULL. It's certainly possible to determine, for any given row, which of those values the row matched, and the answers below indicate how that's done. Am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: @djacobson: The value of `date_occupied` is certainly one of the dates everywhere there is a matching record in the `avail` table, but the result doesn't contain any of those records. It only contains records where the is *no* matching record in the `avail` table.

Comment: @Guffa Noted! I've updated my answer based on your comment. Good eyes. :)

Answer (score 4):

First, it could just be:

```
a.date_occupied IN ('2012-03-07', '2012-03-08', '2012-03-09', '2012-03-10')
```

Or:

```
a.date_occupied BETWEEN '2012-03-07' AND '2012-03-10'
```

And to determine which date was the *match* just examine `a.date_occupied`. Since it's already known to be in the proper range by virtue of the `JOIN` condition you can simply include it in your `SELECT` list.

Comment: That will always return `null` for `a.date_occupied` as the query only returns records where there is no matching record in the `avail` table.

Answer (score 1):

Just add that column to the SELECT list:

```
SELECT h.*, a.date_occupied
     FROM houses h 
LEFT JOIN avail a
```

**Update:** as Guffa points out in the comments, your query is excluding all rows that match the join criteria. I missed that at first. In order to return information (such as the `date_occupied`) about `avail` records which are related to `house` records by *different* criteria, you would need *another* join to expose this data:

```
SELECT h.*, b.date_occupied
     FROM houses h 
LEFT JOIN avail a ON (h.id = a.house_id
                 AND (    a.date_occupied = '2012-03-07'
                       OR a.date_occupied = '2012-03-08'
                       OR a.date_occupied = '2012-03-09'
                       OR a.date_occupied = '2012-03-10'))
LEFT JOIN avail b ON h.id = b.house_id
    WHERE sleeps_count >= '1' -- These columns may need to be qualified 
      AND active = 1          -- if they're on the avail table
      AND a.house_id IS NULL
ORDER BY h.name
```

Or, if you're looking for info from the `avail` records but just want to exclude records with those `date_occupied` values, it would be much simpler to add that constraint after the join (i.e. in the WHERE clause!)

```
SELECT h.*, a.date_occupied
     FROM houses h 
LEFT JOIN avail a ON h.id = a.house_id
    WHERE sleeps_count >= '1'
      AND active = 1
      AND a.date_occupied NOT IN ('2012-03-07','2012-03-08','2012-03-09','2012-03-10')
ORDER BY h.name
```

If neither of these suffice, then I'm afraid I fundamentally misunderstand what you're asking for - and the question may need clarification. :)

Comment: That will always return `null` for `a.date_occupied` as the query only returns records where there is no matching record in the `avail` table.

Comment: @Guffa You're right! I'd completely missed that constraint on the original query. In that case, the OP's question doesn't make a lot of sense! Good catch.

Comment: Thanks for all the thinking here. The avail table lists occupied dates for each house, so the whole left join is to give a list of dates that I want then when the left join *succeeds* in finding a match in the avail table, that also sets a.house_id, which then (correctly) drops that row out of the final results. Based on that, I THINK your first response above will work for me...??

Answer (score 1):

You have to just add the column `date_occupied` in the selection list :

```
   SELECT h.*, a.date_occupied
     FROM houses h 
LEFT JOIN avail a ON (h.id = a.house_id
                 AND (    a.date_occupied = '2012-03-07'
                       OR a.date_occupied = '2012-03-08'
                       OR a.date_occupied = '2012-03-09'
                       OR a.date_occupied = '2012-03-10'))
    WHERE sleeps_count >= '1'
      AND active = 1
      AND a.house_id IS NULL
ORDER BY h.name
```

Comment: That will always return `null` for `a.date_occupied` as the query only returns records where there is no matching record in the `avail` table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which date(s) matched, then you need to remove this from your WHERE clause, since it's currently causing the rows with matching dates to be excluded from the result set:

```
  AND a.house_id IS NULL
```

Once you do that, you can add the a.date_occupied column to the select clause to see which date(s) (if any) matched. If no dates matched, that column will be NULL. Since multiple dates can match, I recommend grouping by h.id and using `GROUP_CONCAT()` to combine all of the dats onto one row.

Here's the final query:

```
   SELECT h.*, group_concat(distinct a.date_occupied order by a.date_occupied)
     FROM houses h 
LEFT JOIN avail a ON (h.id = a.house_id
                 AND (    a.date_occupied = '2012-03-07'
                       OR a.date_occupied = '2012-03-08'
                       OR a.date_occupied = '2012-03-09'
                       OR a.date_occupied = '2012-03-10'))
    WHERE sleeps_count >= '1'
      AND active = 1
GROUP BY h.id
ORDER BY h.name;
```